# XML insert new child for parent with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml

How does one append to an XML file, with a structure such as below, using PHP's `DOMDocument` or `DOMDocumentFragment`.

```
<root>
    <level name="menu1"> 
          <level name="menu1.1"><content name="menu1.1" /></level>
          <level name="menu1.2"><content name="menu1.2" /></level>

          <level name="sub-menu1">
               <level name="sub-menu1.1"><content name="sub-menu1.2"/></level>
          </level>
    </level>

    <level name="menu2"> <!-- Omitted --> 
    </level>
</root>
```

I want to append a new child, as below, to parent: `<level name="menu1">`.

```
<level name="menu1.3"><content name="menu1.3" /></level>
```

I have so far been able to construct the child fully using:

```
$new_dom = new DOMDocument;
$new_level_node = $new_dom->createElement('level');
$new_level_node->setAttribute('name','menu1.3');             
$new_content_node = $new_dom->createElement('content');
$new_content_node->setAttribute('name','menu1.3'); 
$new_level_node->appendChild($new_content_node);
```

But how do I now add `$new_level_node` to my main `XML` above.

For the main XML, I have read it into memory using:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml( $main_xml );
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#82447

Comment: Btw, is Google down in your region?

Comment: I hope many will agree that the docs for DOMDocument is quite messy

Comment: I can add to the root using `$root = $doc->documentElement;` and `$root->appendChild($new_level_node);`. But to add under a specific spot such as under the parent  `<level name=menu1>` is not straightforward, it seems

Comment: Ok, let me give an example. Probably it is really not that easy to find out if you never did that. At least your question is properly crafted, containing a simple example and code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the documentation is quite clear, however you need some patience and hardheadness if you are new to something. These properties are essential for a good programmer (and somebody who wants to become one). Don't always [blame the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662298/xml-insert-new-child-for-parent-with-php-domdocument/32663980#comment53172221_32662298)!

However, I'll give an example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
// Prettify saveXML()
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->load('main.xml');

// Create the child. You don't need to create a new DOMDocument for that
$new_level_node = $doc->createElement('level');
$new_level_node->setAttribute('name','menu1.3');
$new_content_node = $doc->createElement('content');
$new_content_node->setAttribute('name','menu1.3');
$new_level_node->appendChild($new_content_node);

// Now we need to select the menu1 node, in order to call
// appendChild on it. I suggest to use XPath for that.
$xpath_selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$menu1 = $xpath_selector
    ->query('//level[@name="menu1"]')
    ->item(0);

// Append the new node now
$menu1->appendChild($new_level_node);

// Output the modified document
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Let me add that when I've started to learn XML that time, it was also not everything super clear in a minute to me. It took a time unless I got fluent with it.

Comment: For some of us, programming is not all what we do. We could be engineers who need to sort out hardware at the same time, maths professors who also have to prove theorems, or medical doctors who are simply trying to write code. Imagine if you were being this patronising to them. I hope Stack remains a place where genuine questions find their answers, no matter how simple. And major contributors, such as yourself, are rewarded. Just as I shall reward you now with the correct answer. But also please consider this before you go away: `DOXXPath` is not even mentioned once in docs for `DOMDocument`!

Comment: `And major contributors, such as yourself, are rewarded.` .. Hmm. Didn't you forgot to up-vote?